# Textfield size is not increase in storyboard ios

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I have a textfield of 100 width but i want the size of this textfield change on different size screens in same manner. i do not want to give % constraint of screen to increase size. for example in 6s textfield size is 100 but on 7 size should be change on the basis of screen size.

Comment: i set fix width constraint on textfield in 6s

Comment: What manner exactly? You could try to set a leading/trailing constraint?

Comment: i set width constraint to 100 and leading constraint is 50 and top is also 50 in 6s screen, now i want when move to iphone-7 textfield width is increase according to screen  size and in iphone-5 width is decrease and i do not want to set multiplier to my width constraint

Comment: you should use AutoLayout to get appropriate result. refer http://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/

Comment: there is any way by which i can change the width on different screen with these constraints that i have applied?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use constraints, you have to manually change its value accordingly to screen size. You can drag and drop your constraint properties as outlet
[image]

And you can change the constraint by accessing its constant property

```
self.viewWidthConstraint.constant = 20 //Or desired value
```

Comment: there is any other option available except constraint?

Comment: @rajatyadav Yes, you can use Autoresizing as well

Comment: @rajatyadav There are some questions, with good answers in SO about Autoresizing and Auto Layout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434947/in-ios-whats-the-difference-between-autoresizing-autolayout-and-constraints

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754851/autoresizing-masks-programmatically-vs-interface-builder-xib-nib?rq=1

Comment: And one more helpul tutorial to start with auto layout https://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/