# Bind frame to superview bounds UIView extension

Tags: swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Pretty often I find myself writing these lines of code:

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    myView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.superview.topAnchor),
    myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.superview.bottomAnchor),
    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.superview.leadingAnchor),
    myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.superview.trailingAnchor)
])
```

So I'm thinking to write an extension. Something like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func bindFrameToSuperviewBounds() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview.topAnchor),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview.bottomAnchor),
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview.leadingAnchor),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Maybe some built-in function (or technique) like this already exists, I just don't know about it (I've googled a lot, though)
- Isn't (in theory) this code equivalent to:

  ```swift
  myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true   
  myView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
  ```

Why in theory? Because in practice it's definitely not equivalent. This alternative technique didn't ever give me a result I expected to see. The result is pretty much unpredictable.

Answering comments:

[image]

Where:
Green (outer) rectangle is a containerView (UIView).
Purple (inner) rectangle is a UIStackView, which I'm inserting.
As you can see, constraint approach works great.

Next one is a result of autoresizing mask approach:

[image]

Why there are three pictures?
Because the result is different with every new launch of the application!

Comment: To make the non-autolayout example equivalent, you also have to add a `myView.frame = myView.superview.bounds`.

Comment: Possible duplicate for your second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434947/in-ios-whats-the-difference-between-autoresizing-autolayout-and-constraints

Comment: @Rob I've tried all imaginable combinations of all these properties, I've never got the equivalent result. I've just tried your suggestion one more time. Nope.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it's related and interesting. But they don't discuss how to achieve equivalence.

Comment: @Roman Can you explain how, after applying Rob's suggestion, the actual result differs from your expectation?

Comment: This technique of (a) settings the `frame` of the subview to the `bounds` of its superview; and (b) setting the autoresizing mask, is precisely how we used to do this before constraints. I just tested it, and it works fine. You're going to need to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that manifests the problem. Maybe you've got some unrelated code that is changing either the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` or the `autoresizingMask` after the fact. Or you have some other conflicting constraints. But this `autoresizingMask` technique is a tried and true technique...

Comment: Ok, guys, thank you. I will create MCVE and let you know. Maybe a little later.

Comment: @Sweeper I've updated my post, take a look please :)

Comment: You should consider using the [view debugger](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev4dfdedb7a) to diagnose what’s going on. It looks like there are ambiguous constraints, but it’s impossible to tell on the basis of a series of screen snapshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two techniques yield the same behavior:

```
extension UIView {
    func bindFrameToSuperviewBoundsWithConstraints() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.topAnchor),
            bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.bottomAnchor),
            leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.leadingAnchor),
            trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func bindFrameToSuperviewBoundsWithAutoResizingMask() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        frame = superview!.bounds
        autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
}
```

Consider:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    weak var timer: Timer?

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        containerView.clipsToBounds = false

        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        containerView.addSubview(blueView)
        blueView.bindFrameToSuperviewBoundsWithConstraints()

        let redView = UIView()
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        containerView.addSubview(redView)
        redView.bindFrameToSuperviewBoundsWithAutoResizingMask()

        // toggle between the red and blue views

        blueView.isHidden = true

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { _ in
            redView.isHidden = !redView.isHidden
            blueView.isHidden = !blueView.isHidden
        }
    }
}
```

That yields two alternating subviews, each that uses a different technique, illustrating that their frames are the same:

[image]

If you are finding that the autoresizing mask solution is yielding different results than the constraint approach, there must be something else going on.

Comment: Well... it's probably a Maximum Unreproducible Example ))) I've updated my post, take a look please :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use an extension like this:

```
func constraint(to view: UIView, padding: CGFloat = 0) {
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
    self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: padding).isActive = true
    self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -padding).isActive = true
```

and with another one to create a short cut for superview:

```
func constraintToSuperview(padding: CGFloat = 0) {
    guard let superview = self.superview else {
        return
    }
    
    self.constraint(to: superview, padding: padding)
}
```